# What do I call a device like a PlayStation Portable?

Tags: word-choice

Portable/Handheld (Video) Gam(ing) Console/Device?

So many possibilities, how am I supposed to refer to it?

Comment: What do the PSP people say in their official advertising and documentation?

Comment: Interesting take on the situation, [But don't really know where to look](https://www.playstation.com/manual/pdf/PSP-1001K_1.pdf/)

Comment: According to your link, it is called the "PSP system".  And there is a "remote control".

Comment: Yes, they're not very specific.

To be fair, I only used PSP as example. Otherwise I would make an even more confusing question.

Comment: Well. As you say, there are many possibilities. Many of which you have listed. I feel like you've answered your own question right there. What's left to say?

Comment: A uniform term? In my native language, it roughly translates into "Portable Consoles" and that's it.

Comment: What is a PSP? Please define or avoid unnecessary abbreviations that may be unclear to many. It's not as if your title is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the most common term is "handheld [video] game console."  This is the choice for [Wikipedia's article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handheld_game_console):

> A handheld game console is a small, portable self-contained video game console with a built-in screen, game controls, and speakers.[1] Handheld game consoles are smaller than home video game consoles and contain the console, screen, speakers, and controls in one unit, allowing people to carry them and play them at any time or place.[2][3]

You can also see it is used for this [Walmart shopping page](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/handheld-video-game-consoles), although the categorization seems pretty willy-nilly.

"Handheld" is a common shortening you might see in a gaming publication (e.g., [USGamer, "Gaming Deserves Another Handheld Like the Vita"](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/gaming-deserves-another-handheld-like-the-vita)).

I'd avoid using the term "mobile" because it strongly suggests phone games, which are a different category, although certainly one that competes with traditional handhelds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an industry standard.  Thus, as both a gamer and an engineer, I would favor:

PSPish units: Handheld Video Gaming Device

Nintendo DSish units: Portable Video Gaming Device

A full Nintendo-ish system would be called a "Video Gaming Console" (supported by [Merriam Webster definition #5](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/console)).

Why do I like these definitions?  They clearly differentiate how the units are used.  Handheld: in the hands.  Portable: still must be set down on a table.  Console: Expects to be connected to a larger assembly (e.g., a TV).

Comment: The DS and 3DS are definitely handheld by that definition. The Switch might be considered portable, but even then it can be played while held.

Comment: "Mobile Game System"

Comment: Well, yes, they're small enough.  But where the PSP is simply impractical to pay on a table top, the DS/3DS could be played on a table top.  Compare this to a laptop computer that could be played in-hand, but no one would dream of doing it as it's too large and heavy for the purpose.

Comment: Who plays the DS by setting it down on the table?  Most games aren't even playable that way.

Comment: The DS was meant to be held while playing.  Even when sitting at the table the kids still held them while playing.  This insinuation that they were somehow designed to be set on a table is just wrong.